# Add check box function to hidden search table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a check box to my hidden search table, but struggling to figure out how to fit it in (I'm a complete newbie to this stuff).

Currently there are two search boxes, which search two different parameters in the table. I would like to add a tick box that when checked, it will display all the rows that contain the word 'Discontinued'. Then when unchecked, it will hide the table data again.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.active-row)');

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function ContactsearchFX() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput");

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("marketing-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }

  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.active-row)');

  if (input.value.length == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
    
    function ContactsearchFX2() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput2");

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("marketing-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }

  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.active-row)');

  if (input.value.length == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}


elements = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
  if (elements[i].innerHTML === "Discontinued")
    elements[i].style.color = "red";
  if (elements[i].innerHTML === "Manufacturer can't supply")
    elements[i].style.color = "orange";
    if (elements[i].innerHTML === "Stock Available")
    elements[i].style.color = "green";
    if (elements[i].innerHTML === "N/A")
    elements[i].style.color = "lightgrey";
    if (elements[i].innerHTML === "N/A")
    elements[i].style.background = "lightgrey";
}
```

```css
#myInput {
    background-image: url();
    background-size: 25px;
  background-position: 10px 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    border: thin solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput2 {
    background-image: url();
    background-size: 25px;
  background-position: 10px 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    border: thin solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#marketing-table table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    min-width: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

#marketing-table th {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-left: thin solid #dddddd;
    border-right: thin solid #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

#marketing-table td {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-left: thin solid #dddddd;
    border-right: thin solid #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

#marketing-table tbody tr.active-row {
  border-bottom: thin solid #dddddd;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0087AE;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()" placeholder="Search by CODE...">

<input type="text" id="myInput2" onkeyup="ContactsearchFX2()" placeholder="Search by Description...">

<span>
<input type="checkbox">Show all Discontinued
</span>

<table id="marketing-table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <thead>
        <tr class="active-row">
            <th style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Section</th>
            <th style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">CODE</th>
            <th style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Description</th>
            <th style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Sub Category</th>
            <th style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Reason for Out of Stock</th>
            <th style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Expected return date</th>
            <th style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Instruction for replacement</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>Section Example 1</td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>Product Example 1</td>
        <td>Sub Cat Example 1</td>
        <td>Stock Available</td>
        <td>Stock Available</td>
        <td>Stock Available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Section Example 2</td>
        <td>678910</td>
        <td>Product Example 2</td>
        <td>Sub Cat Example 2</td>
        <td>Manufacturer can't supply</td>
        <td>Manufacturer can't supply</td>
        <td>Order as normal, alternative supplier will deliver</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Section Example 3</td>
        <td>34567</td>
        <td>Product Example 3</td>
        <td>Sub Cat Example 3</td>
        <td>Manufacturer can't supply</td>
        <td>Manufacturer can't supply</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Section Example 4</td>
        <td>54321</td>
        <td>Product Example 4</td>
        <td>Sub Cat Example 4</td>
        <td>Discontinued</td>
        <td>Discontinued</td>
        <td>No direct replacement - overface with Stock available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Section Example 5</td>
        <td>87654321</td>
        <td>Product Example 5</td>
        <td>Sub Cat Example 5</td>
        <td>Discontinued</td>
        <td>Discontinued</td>
        <td>No direct replacement - overface with Stock available</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ForgetfulPip/94haes18/5/)

Any push in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you probably want to display the data grid conditionally and that's where you're stuck.
You might need to create a script tag within your html code within which you would need to create a function, in which you would create a node using document.createElement(). Hope this helps. Good luck :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement